# How to automate create and query test through JMeter with Rest API?

Tags: rest, jmeter

I have a workflow engine, with the help of a rest api, i am starting concurrent workflows, each api call returns a uuid. I want to query all these uuid's as well concurrently, how can I do that with jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start workflows and query them within the bounds of a single test - just extract the IDs of started ones using suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and query them using a separate [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers).

If you want to create workflows first and then just query them, i.e. you're not interested in creation time and associated metrics - you can create the workflows in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) and write the uuids into a file using [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/). Then in the "normal" Thread Group use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to read the uuids from the file.